# terraform init command failing on authorization

Tags: linux, terraform

Terraform init is failing on authenticating. I have manually specified access key, etc in the vars file as specified below. 
When I am looking at terraform init log, it is erroring out on different Credential=xxxxxxxxxxxx. I am not sure where it is getting the credential information. I have grep the whole directory for the credential access key xxxxxxxxxxxx and could not find it.
Any ideas on where it is getting that information or can I force it use certain credential

provider "aws" {
  region                 = "${var.aws_region}"
  version                = "~> 2.20"
  skip_region_validation = "true"
  profile                = "xyxyx"
  access_key = "AKYYYYYYYYYYY"
  secret_key = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
}

User-Agent: aws-sdk-go/1.12.75 (go1.10; linux; amd64) APN/1.0 HashiCorp/1.0 Terraform/0.11.4
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=xxxxxxxxxxxx/20191026/Region/s3/aws4_request

2019/10/26 19:57:59 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Response s3/ListObjects Details:
---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/xml
Date: Sat, 26 Oct 2019 19:57:59 GMT
Server: AmazonS3

`AccessDenied`Access Denied

Comment: Coming late to the party, so not sure you're still running into this. The AWS Terraform provider gets its credentials in the following order: static credentials > environment variables > Shared credentials file > EC2 Role. Take a look at the [full authentication documentation for the  AWS provider on the Terraform website](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html#authentication). If I'm reading the documentation correctly, it looks like specifying it in the file should supersede all others, but might as well check to make sure you don't have the others specified as well.

Comment: Thanks Meow_ly, I got it working. I dont remember now, what was causing it at that time.  I agree, its been while